# uigetfile from GUI in Matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I'm trying to import data into a GUI and save it to `handles`. The .mat-file contains a single struct called  `log` with all the data in it. I've made a button using GUIDE and added the following code:

```
function loadMatFileButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.mat');
loadDataName = fullfile(PathName,FileName);
load(loadDataName); % gives log struct

handles.log = log;
```

But when executing I get this error:

```
??? Error using ==> log
Not enough input arguments.

Error in ==> VisualizeData>loadMatFileButton_Callback at 160
handles.log = log;
```

It's really weird. I've tried debugging it by putting a breakpoint after the `load` command. When I then type `handles.log = log` manually in the console, it does works... I don't understand what's going wrong, but it must be really trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short :** The `Not enough input arguments` is the clue to the mystery. It means that you are using a function rather than a variable.

---

First of all, don't use `log`! It is a built in function - natural logarithm. Of course, you can override it, but that is a bad style.

Obviously, you expect that in your code there is some variable named `log` and there isn't. I will leave it as an exercise to the reader to find  out why. **Hint:** Check the .mat file that you are loading.

Comment: Yep, that caused it. I should've known... Thanks a lot!